# Schengen visa and leave entry

Tags: schengen

Can I leave the Schengen point of entry in less than one day to travel to another Schengen country? This is my first time.

Comment: What makes you think you wouldn't be able to ? Are you transiting ?

Answer (score 2):

> Can I leave the Schengen point of entry in less than one day to travel to another Schengen country?

Passports and visas are not normally checked by immigration within the Schengen area and even if they are it doesn't count as an "entry" or "exit". Once you get through the schengen border control you are normally free to travel anywhere in the area (there are a few special visas that are limited to one country but even here there is no systematic enforcement). Internal flights use different terminals that are not subject to border control (you are likely to be asked for ID and will likely have to use your passport for ID but that is an ID check, not an immigration check).

> Thank you for your answer. I am Just wondering if the second country might be strict about it as my visa is issued for the Country number 1.

You are required to select the consulate you apply to based on the details of your visit. If your trip has a main destination you are supposed to apply there, otherwise you are supposed to apply in the country where you will spend the longest. If your stays in different countries are equal then you should apply to the country of entry.

If they think you have lied about your trip to get a visa from a more friendly/conviniant consulate they can use that as grounds to deny you entry or to put a mark on your record when you leave (which will make the chance of getting future visas lower).